# Tor blocked by Internet rimon

Tags: help

i began using tor about 2 weeks ago to bypass  my schools heavily restrictive internet filtering, which is so intense it blocks sites such as Wikipedia, and even google, and even has become an annoyance to much of the school administration. my school's isp is internet rimon, which from the research ive done uses filtering at the modem level rather than standard methods of filtering. for the past 2 weeks I have been able to bypass it using the obsf4 bridge provided with my download. today, however, this has stopped working. ill attempt to describe the problem and what ive tried as best as possible, and Hopefully someone can help me.
when I attempt to start tor, it begins to load, and 1 of 2 things happen, depending on what bridge I'm trying. obsf3 and 4 remain endlessly stuck on "establishing an encrypted directory connection".
fte, meek, and 3 bridges I got from bridgdb load for a while and then give the error message "Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection. Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed"
I have attempted to reinstall tor. the new installation acted exactly identically. 
I ran tor successfully on another network from my computer. I've tried various bridges, ect, as described above.
Please help,
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: could you clarify: the 3 bridges you fetched from BridgeDB, were they obfs4 bridges?

Comment: I'm not sure what they were, just whatever the default is.
-bob

Comment: Try fetching `obfs4` bridges from BridgeDB instead. On the bridges page instead of selecting 'Just give me bridges' scroll down to the Advanced options and try some of the pluggable transports, `obfs4` will be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, ill try it when I get into school in an hour and let you know what happens.

Comment: Getting new obsf4 bridges from bridgedb worked! Thank you so much.
Bob